# compose navigation handle when composable returned after back

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-compose

Let's say I have 2 screens `HomeScreen` and `DetailScreen` and use compose navigation to navigate between screens.

The graph is `HomeScreen` -> `DetailScreen`.

When I pressed back on `DetailScreen` and returned to `HomeScreen` I want `HomeScreen` reacted to that and had to call some method. I want HomeScreen composable to call some method every time he shows up on the screen. How to achieve that?

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "Home"
    ) {
        composable("Home") {
            HomeScreen(
                onDetailClick= {
                    navController.navigate("Detail")
                }
            )
        }
        composable("Detail") {
            DetailScreen(
                onBackClick= {
                    navController.popBackStack()
                },
            )
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NavHostController.navigateUp()` instead of `NavHostController.popBackStack()`, then you can use `LaunchedEffect` with a fixed value like `Unit` for the key.

```
@Composable
HomeScreen() {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        Log.i("HomeScreen", "home screen visible")

        // call your methods here
    }
    
    // the rest of HomeScreen code
}
```

But be careful because everytime configuration change occured it will also be re-executed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how are you back to the home screen. If you use `navController.navigete("home")` then it will work fine.

```
@Composable
HomeScreen() {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        Log.i("HomeScreen", "home screen visible")

        // call your methods here
    }
    
    // the rest of HomeScreen code  
}
```

Or, if you are using `navController.popBackStack()`, then it will not work.

For that, you need to first navigate to Home by using `navController.popBackStack()`
then use `navController.navigate("home")`

example - >

```
navController.popBackStack()
navController.navigete("home")
```

Comment: Navigating without specifying nav options `saveState` and `restoreState` will not restore the backstack, this is a problem since most of the time back pressing shouldn't reset the backstack. I've updated my answer to encourage to use `NavHostController.navigateUp()` instead

Answer (score -1):

you can use viewmodel init block to call the method which you want to execute every time when home screen is loaded. Just make sure that your viewmodel is scoped to the HomeScreen composable.

```
init { // call to your method }
```